# How to install Zoom for online meeting?

Tags: software-installation, software-sources, zoom-meeting

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04.

The latest version of zoom (software-install) I found is 14.

Can anyone help me how to install zoom? I and my wife need it for online classes.

Answer (score 16):

I've been using Zoom on Ubuntu using the official `.deb` file downloaded from their site. However, the latest update (**Version 5.1.412382.0614**) made things look ugly (huge icons, low-res, etc) and behave strangely.

So, after some fiddling around I found that there is a snap of the `zoom-client` that works better than the `.deb` file with the added advantage that it auto-updates. You can install it from the Software Center or from the command line using the following command.

```
sudo snap install zoom-client
```

Comment: Snap packages are generally slow, aren't they? They are easy for the developer but not for end-user?

Comment: And Snap's proprietary – you're liable to end up locked into it, if history's anything to go by.

Comment: I usually avoid using snaps as much as possible, but in this case the snap version of zoom works better than the deb version at least the latest version.

Comment: [zoom-client snap](https://snapcraft.io/zoom-client) isn't offered by Zoom itself. According to the app details page: "*This is an unofficial re-pack of the debian package provided by zoom.us*". And you should use unofficial versions at your own risk.

Comment: If you're using Zoom, an "unofficial repack" should be the least of your privacy concerns...

Comment: Snaps aren't proprietary. However the Zoom client is. If you want to avoid proprietary software you presumably want to avoid Zoom, but given that you want to use Zoom, using Snap isn't a problem. The Zoom snap may be unofficial, but as for "at your own risk" it's safer to use than the official deb, because Snaps run sandboxed and so are better for user security, clean uninstall, and so forth - unlike debs, snaps can't run arbitrary code "as root".

Answer (score 6):

Download the .deb package from [Zoom Download Centre](https://zoom.us/download?os=linux)

### GUI Method

1. Install Gdebi Package Installer through `sudo apt install gdebi`
2. Open the .deb file with Gdebi.
3. Click install.

### CMDline Method

1. Run the following commands in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
   ```

Comment: Why install Gdebi? Ubuntu comes with software for installing `deb` packages with graphical interface out of box.

Comment: @Akib Azmain because it is more user friendly for beginners.

Comment: And this out-of-the-box solution does not work for .deb files that have any dependencies needed to download from the repos. Installation always failed for me in these cases (and you don't know why, since the software does not show any error message besides the fact that installation failed). GDebi handles that perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

From the Zoom download page here: [Download Center - Zoom](https://zoom.us/support/download). Select Ubuntu for Linux Type, make sure the OS Architecture matches your system and select 14.04+.

Once it is downloaded CD into the folder where it was downloaded to and run the following.

```
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Note: This installs it using native tools; however, you might run into issues with dependencies, this should be solved using the `sudo apt install -f` but pay attention to the terminal output to make sure no further steps are needed.

Comment: That's why it's better to install .deb files with GDebi, as it resolves dependencies by itself.

Comment: My preference is to not clutter up my install with more software, just use dpkg and know to check for necessary dependencies. But to each their own. Just another way of installing software. EDIT: sorry first edit came across really passive agressive, sorry

Comment: How do you "clutter" your install using GDebi compared to downloading and installing all required dependencies manually? GDebi does exactly that.

Comment: Because it's another tool you have to install that does the same thing that dpkg does

Comment: If it did the same thing, you would be right. But it doesn't do the same thing, it does more :)

Comment: Two processes to the same end goal. User's choice as to the route they take. One is not intrinsically better than the other, depends solely upon what the user prefers. Less clutter or simple process, take your pick. Not sure why I'm even debating this considering I don't even use Ubuntu anymore lol.